# Linear transformation: how to find domain and range

Tags: linear-algebra

The given matrix is as follows:

$$
(C\mid b) =
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & −1  & 2 \\
3 & 6 & 0 & 12& 4 &  7 \\
1 & 2 & −1 & 5 & −3&  3 \\
2 &4& 2& −1& 3& 0
\end{array}\right)
\rightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c} 
1 &2& 0& 0& 0&  0 \\
0& 0& 1& 0& 0&  1/2 \\
0& 0& 0& 1& 0&  5/8 \\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1&  −1
\end{array}\right)
$$

The question is:
If $C$ is the matrix associated to a linear transformation $L$, what are the domain and range of $L$?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You may find [these questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=find%20image%20of%20matrix) helpful.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from post-multiplying your matrix by any vector in $\mathbb{R}^5$, so the maximal domain is $\mathbb{R}^5$. As for finding the image, solving the augmented matrix for an arbitrary RHS, in terms of variables, will give you the form of an arbitrary member of the image of the the matrix $C$.